# All OS (Pre-installed window 8) gone after installing ubuntu 12.10 (partially installed)

Tags: dual-boot

Few days back I bought a new "TOSHIBA Satellite L855-S5112" laptop . I was just trying to install (Partially Installed) a ubuntu 12.10 along with existing Windows 8 (Pre-installed with this laptop). By mistake I just started to install the new OS in same partition but in between I terminated the installation process. Now I am not able to boot with any OS. 
Help me to recover it with factory installation. Just tell me the step by step process so that I can get recover it. I haven't created the media for recovery.

Answer (score 2):

If you started installed Ubuntu on the same partition that had windows 8 installed, and then aborted the installation, I suspect it will be very difficult to recover directly - the Ubuntu install would start by reformating the partition, which would wipe out the windows 8 install.  I think you'll need to reinstall windows 8 from scratch, and then restart the Ubuntu install.

I've never installed windows 8, so not completely sure of the process - but if Toshiba provided a win 8 DVD with the laptop, you might be able to do that.  I know some vendors provide the win 8 media as a separate partition on the HD, so you might be able to boot from that partition to reinstall.

It might help to indicate exactly which installer options you selected before aborting - this is assuming that you selected the option to install ubuntu on the entire hard drive - if you choose to share the drive, there might be other options available.

Answer (score 1):

Many Toshiba's have a recovery partition which can be accessed by pressing 0 while booting.

That said, there's one option in the Ubuntu installer that erases all partitions on the disc. If you chose that option, I'm afraid your recovery partition is gone and if you did not create Recovery DVD's you'll have to order them from Toshiba.

However, there's still one thing to try before doing this. Boot from the liveDVD or liveUSB, install testdisk by opening a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install testdisk`. Then run testdisk and select **recover partitions**. See if you recognise a partition labelled HDRECOVERY. Probably it is at the end of the hard disk. Try recovering the partition.

If you manage to return your laptop to factory settings then I suggest you create recovery DVD's with Toshiba's utility before trying to install Ubuntu.